# Json data not returning back to success

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Please consider below code. I am loading my products view using below ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
      cache: true,
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      data: json.stringify(data),
      success: function (data) {
          var mainview = $(data).find(".maindiv");
          $('.maindiv').replaceWith(mainview);
                    }
     },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert('Error Occured...... No Products Found');

      },
      complete: function () { subscribeProgress.hide(); }
  });
```

Now when I load this view there is add to cart button for each product on which another ajax call is executed to check if customer is registerd or guest and accordingly popup for register is shown. Now for registering customer, another ajax method is called which works properly but json data is not returned to the success and is directly shown on the page.

Below id code for registering customer through popup

```
$('#formpopupReg').unbind('submit');
        $('#formpopupReg').bind('submit', function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    // you can post your model with this line
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {//Json should get back to this call but doesnt

                        if (data.status == "Wrong email") {
                            $('#modelerrors').text("Wrong email");
                        }

                        if (data.status == "emailexists") {
                            //Code on Error

                        }
                        if (data.status == "registersuccess") {

                            location.reload();
                        }


                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                        alert('Internal Error.');
                    },

                    complete: function () { }

                });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Any solutions.I want json data to return back to success call.

Comment: try in `success: function (data)` to see if the `"data"` is an array or object with `console.log(data)`.

Comment: actually when i load the page with ajax, cant see any jquery code through inspect element

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType:"json"` to your ajax call.

Comment: The problem is only when my view is loaded through ajax call i.e from first ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Try this, problem is your `}` is extra in your code, and missing `dataType: 'json',` if you use `json`.

```
$.ajax({
      cache: true,
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: json.stringify(data),
      success: function (data) {
          var mainview = $(data).find(".maindiv");
          $('.maindiv').replaceWith(mainview);
                    }     
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert('Error Occured...... No Products Found');

      },
      complete: function () { subscribeProgress.hide(); }
  });
```

Comment: I could have pasted wrong but call is working. Tried with ur solution but didnt worked. The problem is only when my view is loaded through ajax call i.e from first ajax call